# The method put<String, ArrayList<superclass>> is not applicable for the argument <String, ArrayList<subclass>>

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Declaration {}

public class Class_object extends Declaration{}
```

above is my class declaration, so basically Class_object is subclass of class Declaration.

```
    Map<String,ArrayList<Declaration>> structure = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Declaration>>();
    ArrayList<Class_object> co = new ArrayList<Class_object>();
    structure.put("CLASS", co);//here gives error:The method put(String, ArrayList<Declaration>) in the type Map<String,ArrayList<Declaration>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Class_object>)
```

In another class, I try to create a hashmap to contain different subclasses of Declaration, but it gives me error message.
Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Do you know why `ArrayList<Declaration> d = new ArrayList<Class_object>();` isn't allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Generics are invariant. You could do

```
Map<String, List<? extends Declaration>> structure 
            = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Declaration>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `extends` keyword to be able to put subclasses of `Declaration` in your map. Define it like so:

```
Map<String,ArrayList<? extends Declaration>> structure = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<? extends Declaration>>();
```

`? extends Declaration` lets java know that you want to be able to use use any classes that extend Declaration, such as Class_object.